# Verify Selection is a Range

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, vsto

In Excel (and likely other Office Apps) `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection` will be of different `Type`, depending of what the user selected: cells, charts, etc.

How do I verify the user selected cells?

`If Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.GetType Is GetType(Excel.Range) then` does not work. The problem seems to be with `GetType(Excel.Range)`, which returns :

> error BC30560: 'Range' is ambiguous in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'

Any ideas?

---

### Update

Source code has been changed to the following, to avoid ambiguous Namespace (if by the way anyone understands what Namespace is conflicting here...?)

```
If Not Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.GetType Is _
   GetType(Global.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range) Then
```

But the `If` statement is still unable to behave correctly when cells are selected.
The Immediate Window tells me:

```
?GetType(global.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)
{Name = "Range" FullName = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range"}
    [Assembly]: {MyExcelVSTO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range, MyExcelVSTO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    Attributes: Public Or ClassSemanticsMask Or Abstract Or Import {4257}
    BaseType: Nothing
    ContainsGenericParameters: False
    CustomAttributes: Count = 6
    DeclaredConstructors: {Length=0}
    DeclaredEvents: {Length=0}
    DeclaredFields: {Length=0}
    DeclaredMembers: {Length=12}
    DeclaredMethods: {Length=7}
    DeclaredNestedTypes: {System.Reflection.TypeInfo.<get_DeclaredNestedTypes>d__23}
    DeclaredProperties: {Length=5}
    DeclaringMethod: 'DirectCast(GetType(global.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range), System.RuntimeType).DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    DeclaringType: Nothing
    FullName: "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range"
    GUID: {00020846-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
    GenericParameterAttributes: 'DirectCast(GetType(global.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range), System.RuntimeType).GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericParameterPosition: 'DirectCast(GetType(global.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range), System.RuntimeType).GenericParameterPosition' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericTypeArguments: {Length=0}
    GenericTypeParameters: {Length=0}
    HasElementType: False
    ImplementedInterfaces: {Length=1}
    IsAbstract: True
    IsAnsiClass: True
    IsArray: False
    IsAutoClass: False
    IsAutoLayout: True
    IsByRef: False
    IsCOMObject: False
    IsClass: False
    IsConstructedGenericType: False
    IsContextful: False
    IsEnum: False
    IsExplicitLayout: False
    IsGenericParameter: False
    IsGenericType: False
    IsGenericTypeDefinition: False
    IsImport: True
    IsInterface: True
    IsLayoutSequential: False
    IsMarshalByRef: False
    IsNested: False
    IsNestedAssembly: False
    IsNestedFamANDAssem: False
    IsNestedFamORAssem: False
    IsNestedFamily: False
    IsNestedPrivate: False
    IsNestedPublic: False
    IsNotPublic: False
    IsPointer: False
    IsPrimitive: False
    IsPublic: True
    IsSealed: False
    IsSecurityCritical: False
    IsSecuritySafeCritical: False
    IsSecurityTransparent: True
    IsSerializable: False
    IsSpecialName: False
    IsUnicodeClass: False
    IsValueType: False
    IsVisible: True
    MemberType: TypeInfo {32}
    MetadataToken: 33554450
    [Module] (System.Reflection.MemberInfo): {MyExcelVSTO.dll}
    [Module]: {MyExcelVSTO.dll}
    Name: "Range"
    [Namespace]: "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
    ReflectedType: Nothing
    StructLayoutAttribute: Nothing
    TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
    TypeInitializer: Nothing
    UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "Range" FullName = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range"}


?Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.GetType
{Name = "__ComObject" FullName = "System.__ComObject"}
    [Assembly]: {mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "System.__ComObject, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    Attributes: Public {1}
    BaseType: {Name = "MarshalByRefObject" FullName = "System.MarshalByRefObject"}
    ContainsGenericParameters: False
    CustomAttributes: Count = 1
    DeclaredConstructors: {Length=1}
    DeclaredEvents: {Length=0}
    DeclaredFields: {Length=1}
    DeclaredMembers: {Length=11}
    DeclaredMethods: {Length=9}
    DeclaredNestedTypes: {System.Reflection.TypeInfo.<get_DeclaredNestedTypes>d__23}
    DeclaredProperties: {Length=0}
    DeclaringMethod: 'DirectCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.GetType, System.RuntimeType).DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    DeclaringType: Nothing
    FullName: "System.__ComObject"
    GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    GenericParameterAttributes: 'DirectCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.GetType, System.RuntimeType).GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericParameterPosition: 'DirectCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.GetType, System.RuntimeType).GenericParameterPosition' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericTypeArguments: {Length=0}
    GenericTypeParameters: {Length=0}
    HasElementType: False
    ImplementedInterfaces: {Length=0}
    IsAbstract: False
    IsAnsiClass: True
    IsArray: False
    IsAutoClass: False
    IsAutoLayout: True
    IsByRef: False
    IsCOMObject: True
    IsClass: True
    IsConstructedGenericType: False
    IsContextful: False
    IsEnum: False
    IsExplicitLayout: False
    IsGenericParameter: False
    IsGenericType: False
    IsGenericTypeDefinition: False
    IsImport: False
    IsInterface: False
    IsLayoutSequential: False
    IsMarshalByRef: True
    IsNested: False
    IsNestedAssembly: False
    IsNestedFamANDAssem: False
    IsNestedFamORAssem: False
    IsNestedFamily: False
    IsNestedPrivate: False
    IsNestedPublic: False
    IsNotPublic: False
    IsPointer: False
    IsPrimitive: False
    IsPublic: True
    IsSealed: False
    IsSecurityCritical: False
    IsSecuritySafeCritical: False
    IsSecurityTransparent: True
    IsSerializable: False
    IsSpecialName: False
    IsUnicodeClass: False
    IsValueType: False
    IsVisible: False
    MemberType: TypeInfo {32}
    MetadataToken: 33554625
    [Module] (System.Reflection.MemberInfo): {CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary}
    [Module]: {CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary}
    Name: "__ComObject"
    [Namespace]: "System"
    ReflectedType: Nothing
    StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
    TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
    TypeInitializer: Nothing
    UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "__ComObject" FullName = "System.__ComObject"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative is to create an IsRange function and to catch any `system.InvalidCastException`, which is the `Type` of `Exception` `thrown` when VB tries to convert the `Selection` into an `Excel.Range`.

For example:

```html
''' <summary>
''' Returns a <see cref="Boolean"/> value indicating wether a selection is a <see cref="Excel.Range"/> Object.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Selection">If not provided, ThisAddIn.Application.Selection is used by default.</param>
''' <returns></returns>
```

```vb
Private Function IsRange(ByVal Optional Selection As Object = Nothing) As Boolean
    If Selection Is Nothing Then Selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection
    Try
        Dim MyRange As Excel.Range = Selection
    Catch ex As system.InvalidCastException
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your references.

I am able to see the issue, When I included the references to both `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and `Microsoft office 15.0 object library`. Later I tried with only first one. The issue is gone.

If there is no issue with references, then try as said below.

First get the object of the active work sheet.

Then using the worksheet object check for the selection

```
Dim wsSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)    

If wsSheet.Cells.Application.Selection.GetType Is GetType(Excel.Range) Then

End If
```

Comment: The problem is still with GetType(Excel.Range). Is the code you proposed working for you?

Comment: Now I am able to repro your issue, When I included the references to both "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" and "Microsoft office 15.0 object library". Now I removed the second one. The issue is gone. so check your references first.

Comment: I did not have `Microsoft Office 15.0 object library` referenced, nor 16.0. What is strange is that I then have `Dim Selection as Excel.range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection` and it works perfectly..

Comment: Are you using VB.Net or VBA? I did not pick it up in the first place, but when you mention `ThisWorkbook` I cannot think of anything other than VBA.

Comment: Changing your code for `Dim wsSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)`, `wsSheet.Cells.Application.Selection.Cells.Application.Selection.GetType` then generates the exact same `Type` details as my `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.GetType` so it does not change anything and I believe the problem remains in `GetType(Excel.Range)`